# Invariant Violation when upgrading React Native and dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

It's been a while since I updated my React Native project dependancies, and I'm trying to bring everything up to date. I started on `react-native@0.42.0` and `react@15.4.1`. I updated everything using `npm install --save react-native@x.x.x`.

Now that I've updated everything, I can't get my app to run. I'm getting the following error:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a strong (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:object

As a last ditch effort to debug, I've done the following:

Commented out all application code so the only code running is inside index.android.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import CRV from './app'
AppRegistry.registerComponent('CRV', () => CRV)
```

Modified my packages.json file so that only react and react-native are loading:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.0.0-beta.5",
  "react-native": "^0.49.1"
}
```

When I run my app, I'm getting the red screen:

[image]

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to proceed at this point. Perhaps I've commented out too much and there's some other code I need to let run before trying to isolate the problem?

Comment: To debug, we also need to see `app.js` since we import it.

Comment: Did you do `react-native upgrade`?

Comment: @MikeRapadas I actually don't have an app.js. I do have an `/app/index.js` file. Is that the same thing?

Comment: In this case, yes. `import Carve from './app'` will resolve to `/app/index.js`

Comment: @AndrewLi I did run that command, but I chose "no" each time it asked me if I wanted to replace my version with the newest version. Do you need to inspect each new template to cherry pick all new code?

Comment: @MikeRapadas great, thanks for your confirmation. so what i've posted above is everything in the `app/index.js` file. I also went ahead basically commented out that whole file (which I had forgotten to do) and I still get the same error.

Comment: I find that after upgrading modules in react-native i often need to delete my build folder to make it work again (ios simulator). ios>build

Comment: @Eran is there an equivalent for android? I’ve been deleting node_modules and running `npm install` but that’s not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer isn't very glamorous.

Fortunately I was doing all my work on a branch. I had used `react-native upgrade` originally, and that's what lead me to this fail.

I finally destroyed that branch and got my environment back up on 0.42.0. I then used the new `react-native-git-upgrade` ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html#upgrade-based-on-git)). It was still a very tedious process, but once I updated all my other dependencies and fixed issues in my code related to requirements from the upgrade, it worked.